# Integrated Graphics

Tags: motherboard, integrated-graphics

I'm thinking of buying [this](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=G31M-S) motherboard, and it has integrated graphics, and I'm building a budget PC, £150 ish, so I'm wondering if it would be worth getting a graphics card? [This](http://www.aria.co.uk/Products/Components/Graphics+Cards/PCI-E/nVIDIA+GeForce+8+Series/Gigabyte+GeForce+8400+GS+512MB+DDR2+PCI-Express+Graphics+Card+?productId=38173) one seems quite cheap, but I just want to know for definite that the integrated graphics won't be better than the graphics card? I don't think it will, but I'm not sure how advanced integrated graphics are now.

Comment: What is the PC going to be used for?

Comment: not much, it's a budget build as the question says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the graphics card will be better than the integrated chip. If nothing else the integrated chip will use the main memory for display, thus reducing the amount of memory you have available to applications.

NVidia GeForce are generally good.